# Proving the summation

Tags: sum, discrete-mathematics

[image]

Not sure how to go about doing this question. It says that finding the derivative of (1+x)^n is useful!

Comment: You'll probably get better responses on http://math.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Hint: [Proof by induction](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mathematical_induction)...

Answer (score 0):

Given the binomial formula:

[image]

substituting 1 for y, the formula reads:

[image]

Now taking the derivative of both sides:

[image]

You're almost there (consider the term of the summation you get for k=0).

---

A different (simple) approach is using the [absorption identity for binomial coefficients](https://mikespivey.wordpress.com/2012/12/10/absorption-identity/):

[image]